# Friction coating aluminum parts in lieu of anodizing

Tags: friction, aluminum

I have an application, 6061-T6 aluminum cylinder, and piston - approx 6" dia for both, O-ring on position. The piston is under 80-100 psi, room temp and stroke are a couple of inches.

Typically, we would use clear anodize on both to reduce friction and control corrosion. This is not possible based on the manufacturing location we might use - overseas and thus I have been looking into alternative coatings/finishes - such as Tungsten Disulfide, but the method of application, pneumatic, might not be an idea given the geometry - not sure.
Anyway, Tribology isn't my field and thought I would ask if others have been similarly challenged (anodizing is a no-brainer after all).

Comment: Is the problem with anodizing regulatory or technical? There are more eco-friendly techniques than sulphuric acid.

Comment: Regulatory. Thanks for tip on eco-friendly methods. I will do some research here.